# Cache with automatically expiring items

Tags: java, guava

Is there a Cache implementation available in Java, Guava, or another library that can do the following:

- Key, Value Cache with automatically expiring items. Modifying the value restarts the expiration timer. Each key/value pair expires separately (has it's own timer).
- Items can be manually added, for example, `cache.put(key, value);`

I have seen the Guava `LoadingCache` but that implementation requires you to implement the `load(key)` method. The `load(key)` method is intended to compute a value based on the key by using a database or other resource. Once that value is computed by the `load(key)` method I believe the `LoadingCache` sticks the resulting (key, value) pair in the cache.

My implementation requirements differ from the `LoadingCache` because my keys will remain fixed, but the corresponding values will be slowly updated as I scrape my database. In other words, I don't want to load the entire value at once like the LoadingCache does in it's `load(key)` method - I want to leave the key the same and incrementally update the value Object depending on what I get from the database. So it would appear that this precludes using the `LoadingCache` since the `load(key)` method forces you to load the key's corresponding value all at once.

The reason I want to incrementally load the value (for each key) is because it's going to take a long time and I am using AJAX polling to keep the user updated. Therefore loading it all at once is useless. I want to cache these values so I can easily retrieve them with AJAX. I want them to expire because once the user is done visiting the webpage, they are useless.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you wouldn't use the Guava `LoadingCache` and _not_ load the key's corresponding value all at once in the `load` method, instead having your `load` method pass the task of the ongoing loading to some other `ExecutorService`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ok so then what? In my ExecutorService which would be a thread, what do I call on the LoadingCache to update the key? If I just put the EmptyObject in as the value when I call load(), then I call ExecutorService(EmptyObject), and I update the fields on EmptyObject, will the cache automatically "reset" it's expiration time for that key/value pair?

Comment: No, though you could make it do so by calling `cache.put` after you're done loading, which would trigger a new write as far as `expireAfterWrite` is concerned.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I see. So couldn't I also ignore load() altogether (implement it to return null) and just always use get() and put()? It seems like that would use the timer features of the cache but ignore the load features that I don't want...and get() says it can call load() but why would it, if I already put() stuff there beforehand. Also, if it returns null when I haven't put() yet, that's fine...

Comment: It might be _simpler_ to do it with a `CacheLoader`.  You can't return `null` from the `CacheLoader`, but you could just _not provide_ a `CacheLoader`, and use the `Cache` interface instead of `LoadingCache`.  Also, adding the entry to the `Cache` with a `CacheLoader` makes sure you won't accidentally recompute the value more than once.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Please confirm: I think what you're saying is that in the load() method I can start the ExecutorService, pass in an Object, let's say SlowlyFilledObj. Then I should return SlowlyFilledObj in the load() method. In the ExecutorService itself, I should update the cache value for SlowlyFilledObj by using put(key, SlowlyFilledObj). 

This all seems workable but it's unintuitive that I need to call "get" to cause the cache to start loading for a particular key. You'd think calling "put" would do that. Also feel free to post as answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: You can't add things that automatically trigger with `put`; I'm saying saying that you have to a) add something to the cache as soon as you want to start loading, so you won't have conflicts; b) that it's easier to trigger the full load automatically in a `CacheLoader` rather than having to do extra fancy stuff in the cache users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Louis Wasserman's advice I implemented the following code:

```
LoadingCache<String, WorkerItem> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
.concurrencyLevel(level) 
.maximumSize(size)
.expireAfterWrite(seconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.removalListener(this)
.build(
    new CacheLoader<String, WorkerItem>() {
        public WorkerItem load(String key) throws Exception {
            WorkerItem workerItem = new MoreSpecificWorkerItem();
            workerItem.setTask(key);
            Controller.beginWorking(workerItem); //Runs in thread pool
            return workerItem;
        }
    }
);
```

When the user calls get() on the Cache it will immediately return the `WorkerItem` and will be populating it in the background. As long as you implement `WorkerItem` with an `isFinished()` method or similar, it will be possible to know when it's ready for use.

And I implemented a cleanup service since the cache does not periodically remove expired items. Expired items are simply marked dirty and are removed the next time you access them or the next time cleanup is called.

```
final Runnable doCleanup = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        LoadingCache<K, V> cache = getCache();
        cache.cleanUp();
        }
    }

ScheduledFuture<?> cleanupHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(doCleanup, 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
return cleanupHandle;
```

Answer (score 1):

[JCS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/) supports idle time expiration and manual adds

Comment: looks fairly complex. by default it uses a cache config file according to the documentation. I can't justify using something like that to my tech lead without good reason. also, I only need one cache or "region" in JCS terminology. And I only have one server not distributed.